# HTML5 restore canvas after clearing

Tags: html, save, restore, html5-canvas

I have a function that draws a collection of images to the canvas and it saves it after.

Then in the command line I run:

```
canvas.save();
canvas.clearRect(0,0,415,415);
canvas.restore();
```

I expect it to restore it, but it does nothing. Any help, I can't find anything on google about running in this series, and i've had this problem a few times in the past.

Comment: you can check this 
[Updating Canvas content on onmouseover and onmouseout][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273252/updating-canvas-content-on-onmouseover-and-onmouseout

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're misinterpreting what `save` does.  It saves the state of the canvas, which is affected by `rotate`, `translate`, `scale`, etc.  It does not save any of the actual content of the canvas.  If you want to save what's actually on the canvas, try storing it in a hidden canvas.  Assuming you've added the hidden canvas to the html and gotten its context object (`canvas2`), the following should save it:

```
canvas2.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0)
```

And then to restore it:

```
canvas.drawImage(canvas2, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use getImageData and putImageData to save and restore canvas content.

```
tmp = context.getImageData(0,0,415,415);
context.clearRect(0,0,415,415);
context.putImageData(tmp,0,0);
```

Comment: Much more CPU efficient than draw, clear and redraw.

Comment: This seems much cleaner than using a hidden canvas like the other answer.